# Update database instead of adding a row in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have code that is working to add new row into my site profile table but when someone tries to update the profile, I am not sure how to handle that. I am updating multiple tables from the controller.

I have following code. I check in customers table if ID is already present, if yes, then I change the state of entity to be modified.(I found this code online). I have commented out the next line because it was giving me an error.

This code does not throw any error on saving changes but it does not update the database.

```
    var oldCustomer = _context.Customers.Find(objSv.CustomerServices.strUserID);
     var oldCustomerServices = _context.CustomerServices;

    if (oldCustomer == null) {
      _context.Customers.Add(obj);
      _context.CustomerServices.Add(objSv.CustomerServices);
        }
     else
     {
       _context.Entry(oldCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
 //  _context.Entry(oldCustomerServices).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

   _context.SaveChanges();
```

I would like database to be updated with new object. These are my new objects with new data

```
        CustomerProfile obj = GetCustomerProfile();
        ServiceProvider objSv = GetServiceProvider();`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the following line:

```
var oldCustomerServices = _context.CustomerServices;
```

Here `_context.CustomerServices` is not a `CustomerServices` object. Its a `DbSet` of `CustomerService` but you are treating like a `CustomerServices` object.

I think your code should be as follows:

```
var oldCustomerServices = _context.CustomerServices.Find(CustomerServices.Id); // <-- I have assumed primary key name of `CustomerServices` is `Id`. If anything else then use that.

if(oldCustomerServices == null)
{
    CustomerServices newCustomerServices = new CustomerServices()
    {
      // Populate the customer service property here
    }
    _context.CustomerServices.Add(newCustomerServices);
} 
else
{
     _context.Entry(oldCustomerServices).State = EntityState.Modified;
}


var oldCustomer = _context.Customers.Find(objSv.CustomerServices.strUserID);

if (oldCustomer == null) 
{
   Customer newCustomer = new Customer()
   {
       // Populate the customer property here
   }

   _context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
  _context.CustomerServices.Add(objSv.CustomerServices);
}
else
{
  _context.Entry(oldCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I tried the above but it still does not update the database. I removed the customer services part and only tried to update oldCustomer with _context.Entry(oldCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
}